# Pandas: How to store cProfile output in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, profiling

There already exist some posts discussing python profiling using cProfile, as well as the challenges of analyzing the output due to the fact that the output file **restats** from the sample code below is not a plain text file. The snippet below is only a sample from [docs.python.org/2/library/profile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html), and not directly reproducible.

```
import cProfile
import re
cProfile.run('re.compile("foo|bar")', 'restats')
```

There is one discussion here: [Profile a python script using cProfile into an external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470217/profile-a-python-script-using-cprofile-into-an-external-file?rq=1), and on the [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) there are more details on how to analyze the output using **pstats.Stats** (still only a sample, and not reproducible):

```
import pstats
p = pstats.Stats('restats')
p.strip_dirs().sort_stats(-1).print_stats()
```

I may be missing some very important details here, but I would really like to store the output in a **pandas DataFrame** and do further analysis from there.

I thought it would be pretty simple since the output in iPython from running `cProfile.run()` looks fairly tidy:

```
In[]:
cProfile.run('re.compile("foo|bar")'

Out[]:
```

[image]

Any suggestions on how to get this into a pandas DataFrame in the same format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like https://github.com/ssanderson/pstats-view might do what you want (albeit with unnecessary dependencies related to visualising the data and making it interactive):

```
>>> from pstatsviewer import StatsViewer
>>> sv = StatsViewer("/path/to/profile.stats")
>>> sv.timings.columns
Index(['lineno', 'ccalls', 'ncalls', 'tottime', 'cumtime'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Installation command: `pip install git+https://github.com/ssanderson/pstats-view.git@master`

Comment: This library seems not to work anymore. It throws an error when importing. Not surprising, considering the `requirements.txt` on their GitHub is now empty :\

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is a few old, but I found an easy way to solve it.

```
import cProfile
import pandas as pd

with cProfile.Profile() as pr:
    # run something

df = pd.DataFrame(
    pr.getstats(),
    columns=['func', 'ncalls', 'ccalls', 'tottime', 'cumtime', 'callers']
)
```

Answer (score 8):

I know this already has an answer, but for anyone who doesn't want to go to the trouble of downloading another module, here's a rough and ready script that should get close:

```
%%capture profile_results    ## uses %%capture magic to send stdout to variable
cProfile.run("your_function( **run_parms )")
```

Run the above first, to populate `profile_results` with the contents of stout, which contains the usual printed output of `cProfile`.

```
## Parse the stdout text and split it into a table
data=[]
started=False

for l in profile_results.stdout.split("\n"):
    if not started:
        if l=="   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)":
            started=True
            data.append(l)
    else:
        data.append(l)
content=[]
for l in data:
    fs = l.find(" ",8)
    content.append(tuple([l[0:fs] , l[fs:fs+9], l[fs+9:fs+18], l[fs+18:fs+27], l[fs+27:fs+36], l[fs+36:]]))
prof_df = pd.DataFrame(content[1:], columns=content[0])
```

It wont win any prizes for elegance or pleasant style, but it does force that table of results into a filterable dataframe format.

```
prof_df
```

[image]

Comment: Great quick n' dirty answer. Using the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) method eliminates the need of the `started` bool. Simply pass `profile_results.stdout.split()` into `enumerate()` to return an indexed iterable.

Comment: Yep, this was all I needed, would just add that a quick:

`prof_df.columns=prof_df.columns.str.strip()`

is needed to preserve the original column names.

Answer (score 2):

In case people don't want to use %%capture or go through a CSV, below a cobbled-together solution, in this case comparing multiple cProfiles in the same folder by (1) sorting each cProfile by cumulative time and (2) adding only the top result (`pstats.Stats(f, stream = p_output).sort_stats("cumulative").print_stats(1)`) from each .prof to a data frame (along with a portion of the .prof filename to identify which profile the measurement came from).

See [here](https://github.com/Dimildizio/game_profile/blob/57ae468cab8fca2ce14d9e46ff0e82b7f5f1343d/profile_me.py) for some of the original code (which does use CSVs as the intermediary).

```
import io
import pstats
import pandas as pd
import glob

all_files = glob.glob(profiledir + "/*.prof")

li = []

for f in all_files:
    
    p_output = io.StringIO()

    prof_stats = pstats.Stats(f, stream = p_output).sort_stats("cumulative").print_stats(1)

    p_output = p_output.getvalue()
    p_output = 'ncalls' + p_output.split('ncalls')[-1]
    result = '\n'.join([','.join(line.rstrip().split(None,5)) for line in p_output.split('\n')])

    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(result), sep=",", header=0)
    df['module name'] = f.split(' ')[0].split('\\')[1] # differs depending on your file naming convention
    li.append(df) 

df = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your doing this in the cmd with
`python -m cProfile your_script.py`

you can push the output to a csv file and then parse with pandas
`python -m cProfile your_script.py >> output.txt`

Then parse the output with pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('output.txt', skiprows=5, sep='    ', names=['ncalls','tottime','percall','cumti    me','percall','filename:lineno(function)'])
df[['percall.1', 'filename']] = df['percall.1'].str.split(' ', expand=True, n=1)
df = df.drop('filename:lineno(function)', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to accomplish this task

```
def convert_to_df(path, offset=6):
    """
    path: path to file
    offset: line number from where the columns start
    """
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        core_profile = f.readlines()
    core_profile = core_profile[offset:]
    cols = core_profile[0].split()
    n = len(cols[:-1])
    data = [_.split() for _ in core_profile[1:]]
    data = [_ if len(_)==n+1 else _[:n]+[" ".join(_[n+1:])] for _ in data]
    data_ = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
    return data_
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recipe:

```bash
python -m cProfile -o profile.pstats some.py
```

And then

```py
from pstats import Stats
import pandas as pd

st = Stats('./profile.pstats')

keys_from_k = ['file', 'line', 'fn']
keys_from_v = ['cc', 'ncalls', 'tottime', 'cumtime', 'callers']
data = {k: [] for k in keys_from_k + keys_from_v}

s = st.stats

for k in s.keys():
    for i, kk in enumerate(keys_from_k):
        data[kk].append(k[i])

    for i, kk in enumerate(keys_from_v):
        data[kk].append(s[k][i])

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('./profile.csv')
```